# How to access view's subviews without crash while hooking Swift? (Jailbreak)

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak

I have an odd issue where when I change the background of a view, I can no longer see the UILabels that are subviews of that view. I cannot dump the headers for the Calculator app, as it is in Swift, and I don't know what the name of the UILabels are, and FLEXing is no help with that. I want to bring the subviews in front of the background view (there are two subviews), but both of my current methods crash the target app. I was trying to see if I could get it working with just one at the very front though.

My code:

```
NSMutableArray *labels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:((DisplayView*)self).allSubviews];
if ([labels count] > 0) {

    UILabel *mainLabel = labels[0];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:mainLabel];
    }

((DisplayView*)self).allSubviews = labels;
```

And I have also tried:

```
    for (UILabel *label in ((DisplayView*)self).allSubviews) {
        if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        [self bringSubviewToFront:label];
}
```

I need an alternative method of doing this, a way to bring *all* of the subviews forward, or someone to tell me what I am doing wrong.
Edit, here's my full code:

```
    @interface DisplayView
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) UIColor *backgroundColor;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite, getter=isHidden) BOOL hidden;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite, getter=isOpaque) BOOL opaque;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) CGFloat alpha;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSArray *allSubviews;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) CALayer *layer;
@end

%hook DisplayView
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    ((DisplayView*)self).opaque = NO;
    ((DisplayView*)self).backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
     ((DisplayView*)self).hidden = NO;
((DisplayView*)self).alpha = 1.0;

NSMutableArray *labels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:((DisplayView*)self).layer.sublayers];
if ([labels count] > 0) {

    UILabel *mainLabel = labels[0];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:mainLabel];
}



}



%end

%ctor {
    %init(DisplayView=objc_getClass("Calculator.DisplayView"));
}
```

Comment: Instead of bringing the labels to the front could you not send the background to the back.

Comment: All I did though was change the background colour. Besides, I can't find the background view by itself

Comment: I see.  Well changing the background colour shouldn't affect the position of the views in the hierarchy.  If you can't find the background view how did you change the background colour.  Can you update with that code.

Comment: I get an error when I use 'self', something about it not being found on object of type 'id' so i have to do this:                       
        ((DisplayView*)self).opaque = NO;
 ((DisplayView*)self).backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 ((DisplayView*)self).hidden = NO;
 ((DisplayView*)self).alpha = 1.0;

Comment: If you could show the code where you are doing that (full method if possible) then it would help.  So the class is a DisplayView by the way you are forcing the case.  Can't you just do something like `[((DisplayView*)self).superview sendSubviewToBack:(DisplayView*)self];`  (I think that's correct syntax).  Although if you are just changing what you show it shouldn't even be needed.

Comment: Its only called displayview because i chose to call it that; theos won't allow dots in class names. Therefore i have to do %ctor and  
    `%init(DisplayView=objc_getClass("Calculator.DisplayView"));`

Comment: Can you post all of the code where you do this so we can see it.

Comment: I've just noticed that you are creating an array of sub layers and trying to cast the first one to a UILabel.   This isn't going to work you want an array of the sub views of the view something like this `NSMutableArray *labels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:((DisplayView*)self).subviews];'

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a few possible issues. First, there is no `allSubviews` on `UIView`, it probably should be `subviews`.

```
NSMutableArray *labels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:((DisplayView*)self).subviews];
if ([labels count] > 0) {
  UILabel *mainLabel = labels[0];
```

(Just want point out that you don't seem to change the array, so why copy it? You can directly access `self.subviews`)

Second, in the `CALayer` version, you're casting `CALayer` to `UIView`:

```
NSMutableArray *labels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:((DisplayView*)self).layer.sublayers];
CALayer *mainLabel = labels.firstObject;
if (mainLabel) {
  [labels removeObjectAtIndex:0];
  [labels addObject:mainLabel];
  self.layer.sublayers = labels;
}
```

Maybe some of this helps

Comment: For some reason, neither work. The label still isn't showing up